# Exception has occurred: KeyError 'h' File "C:\Users\username\Downloads\test.py", line 19, in dfs, how to fix?

Tags: python

```
# Python dictionary to act as an adjacency list
graph = {
  'a' : ['b','c'],
  'b': ['d', 'e'],
  'd': ['h','i'],
  'e': ['j', 'k'],
  'c' : ['f','g'],
  'g': ['l','m']
}

visited = [] # List of visited nodes of graph.
def dfs(visited, graph, node):
    
    if node not in visited:
        visited.append(node)
    

    for neighbor in graph[node]:
        dfs(visited, graph, neighbor)
    print(node)

# Driver Code
print("Following is the Depth-First Search")
dfs(visited, graph, "a")
print("visited=",visited)
```

How do I fix this error.

This is a tree. To visualize that you need to know that a has two child b and c.

b has 2 child d and e

d has 2 child h and i

e has 2 child j and k and so on.

I ran a similar code but with numbers in those graph like 7,8 etc instead of a,b,c. It ran perfectly. But here in this case it is not running. Can you debug this

Comment: Well, there is no "h" key in `graph`. Or any of the other childs past "g", like "i", "j" etc.

Comment: helpful helpful..  here you take the awar

Comment: Well, stop recursing when a child/neighbour doesn't exist in the graph.

Comment: Or use [a module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/graphlib.html) that is actually written for graphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot descend from the leaf nodes. Leaf nodes do not have children and thus are not the keys in `graph` dictionary.

```
...
    for neighbor in graph[node]:
        if neighbor in graph.keys():  #not leaf
            dfs(visited, graph, neighbor)
        else
            visited.append(neighbor)
```